# Get a NoSuchElementException for InternetExplorerDriver using Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am getting the following exception by executing the code below. The code works with the FirefoxDriver, only the InternetExplorerDriver fails.
I also added the HTML & Java code now.

Exception:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with id == devices_Number (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Command duration or timeout: 316 milliseconds

For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html

Build info: version: '2.44.0', revision: '76d78cf', time: '2014-10-23 20:03:00'

System info: host: 'ICA4502', ip: '192.168.5.37', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_09'

Session ID: dac482ae-dba1-4d57-807c-de22e443f9b1

Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver

Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, javascriptEnabled=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ignoreZoomSetting=false, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=false, browserName=internet explorer, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss, version=9, ie.usePerProcessProxy=false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, requireWindowFocus=false, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:40748/, handlesAlerts=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, nativeEvents=true, browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, takesScreenshot=true}]

at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)

       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:599)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:352)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:393)

       at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:214)

       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:344)

       at com.java.selenium.example.SeleniumTest.startTest(SeleniumTest.java:30)

       at com.java.selenium.example.SeleniumTest.main(SeleniumTest.java:15)
```

Following is the html file Test.Html

```
 

<html>

<head>

<title>Multi select Drop Down List Box</title>

</head>

<body>

<p>What all devices do you listen to music on?</p>

<BR>

<INPUT id="devices_Number" name="devices_Number_n"  maxLength="10" value="Devices Number" >

<INPUT id="devices_Name" name="devices_Name_n"  maxLength="10" value="Devices Name" >

<INPUT id="devices_Made" name="devices_Made_n"  maxLength="10" value="Devices Made By" >

<INPUT id="devices_Version" name="devices_Version_n"  maxLength="10" value="Devices Version" >

</body>

</html>
```

Following is the selenium java file SeleniumTest .java

```
package com.java.selenium.example;

 

import java.io.File;

 

import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;

 

/**

*

 * @author

 *

*/

public class SeleniumTest  {

           

            private static WebDriver driver = null;

            private final static String URL= "D:\\Selenium\\Text.html";

            private final static String IE_DRIVER = "D:\\Dev_Env\\Tester\\driver\\IEDriverServer_2.44\\IEDriverServer.exe";

            /**

            * main method

            * @param args

            * @throws Exception

            */

            public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

                        startTest();

            }

           

            /**

            *  startTest

             */

            private static void startTest() {

                        try {

                                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", new File(IE_DRIVER).getAbsolutePath());

                                    //driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();

                                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                                    driver.get(URL);

                                    Thread.sleep(2000);

                                   

                                    driver.findElement(By.id("devices_Number")).clear();

                                    Thread.sleep(200);

                                    driver.findElement(By.id("devices_Number")).sendKeys("123456");

 

                        } catch (Exception e ) {

                                    e.printStackTrace();

                        }

            }

}
```

Comment: Here Id looks wrong : driver.findElement(By.id("devices_Number")).clear();

Comment: Better explanation and cleanup

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30000);          
driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("devices_Number")));
```

Comment: HI Thanks , this is working.... can pls explain what is the difference between visibilityOfElementLocated & presenceOfElementLocated, and which can be preferred first

Comment: @SANECE04 `presenceOfElementLocated` will be slighty faster because it's just check elements presence on the page while the `visibilityOfElementLocated` has to check the presence and whether is element visible. you can refer http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html for more info...... Please Mark the answer correct(✓) if you feel it solves the question.